# Average the first row by group from data.table lookup

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to average the most recent company rows, for each individual which occur before a specified date.

In other words I would like to average the most recent (for each company) previous alpha values for each individual and for each date.

```
table1 <- fread(
  "individual_id | date       
       1             |  2018-01-02
       1             |  2018-01-04
       1             |  2018-01-05
       2             |  2018-01-02
       2             |  2018-01-05", 
  sep ="|"
)
table1$date = as.IDate(table1$date)
table2 <- fread(
  "individual_id | date2       | company_id | alpha
       1             |  2018-01-02 |     62       |  1     
       1             |  2018-01-04 |     62       |  1.5 
       1             |  2018-01-05 |     63       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-01 |     71       |  2     
       2             |  2018-01-02 |     74       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-05 |     74       |  4",
  sep = "|"
)
```

So for example:

- observation 1 in table 1 is individual "1" on the 2018-01-02.
- To achieve this I look in table 2 and see that individual 1 has 1 instance prio or on the 2018-01-02 for a company 62. Hence only 1 value to average and the mean alpha is 1.

example 2:

- observation for individual 2 on 2018-01-05.
- here there are 3 observations for individual 2, 1 for company 71 and 2 for company 74, so we choose the most recent for each company which leaves us with 2 observations 71 on 2018-01-01 and 74 on 2018-01-05, with alpha values of 2 and 4, the mean alpha is then 3.

The result should look like:

```
table1 <- fread(
      "individual_id | date         | mean alpha
       1             |  2018-01-02  | 1
       1             |  2018-01-04  | 1.5
       1             |  2018-01-05  | (1.5+1)/2 = 1.25
       2             |  2018-01-02  | (2+1)/2 = 1.5
       2             |  2018-01-05  | (2+4)/2 = 3", 
      sep ="|"
    )
```

I can get the sub sample of the first row from table2 using:

```
table2[, .SD[1], by=company_id]
```

But I am unsure how limit by the date and combine this with the first table.

**Edit**

This produces the result for each individual but not by company.

```
table1[, mean_alpha := 
         table2[.SD, on=.(individual_id, date2 <= date), mean(alpha, na.rm = TRUE), by=.EACHI]$V1]


individual_id    date    mean_alpha
1   2018-01-02  1.000000
1   2018-01-04  1.250000
1   2018-01-05  1.166667
2   2018-01-02  1.500000
2   2018-01-05  2.333333
```

Comment: From your expected output: I don't get why individual 1, company 62, dates prior to 2018-01-04 is not (1+1.5)/2. Neither I understand why individual 1, company 63, dates prior to 2018-01-05 is (1.5+1)/2 instead of 1, its only value. If you elaborate more on what you need, then we could try to help.

Comment: many thanks for the response, as I stated in the question I am seeking to average the **most recent** value for each company. Hence for individual 1, on 2018-01-04, the most recent is 1.5 for company 62, company 63's value has not appeared yet. Table 1 is on an individual basis and hence I aggregate (average) for more than one company, but only using the **most recent** values. Apologies if I did not make it clear.

Comment: Still not clear, sorry I couldn't help :(

Comment: I want to average the most recent previous alpha values for each individual and for each date. Does this make more sense?

Comment: I can parse "most recent" together with "for each date". I can imagine **either** by date or for dates before `xyz`. But don't worry, I may be tired already. Maybe someone else can get what your need and provide an answer

Comment: ok, no worries. I added 2 examples to try and clarify my objective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194957/discussion-between-laurence-jj-and-pavodive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible approach:

```
#ensure that order is correct before using the most recent for each company
setorder(table2, individual_id, company_id, date2)

table1[, mean_alpha := 
    #perform non-equi join
    table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
        #for each row of table1,
        by=.EACHI,
        #get most recent alpha by company_id and average the alphas
        mean(.SD[, last(alpha), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
    ]
```

output:

```
   individual_id       date mean_alpha
1:             1 2018-01-02       1.00
2:             1 2018-01-04       1.50
3:             1 2018-01-05       1.25
4:             2 2018-01-02       1.50
5:             2 2018-01-05       3.00
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- fread(
    "individual_id | date       
       1             |  2018-01-02
       1             |  2018-01-04
       1             |  2018-01-05
       2             |  2018-01-02
       2             |  2018-01-05", 
    sep ="|"
)
table1[, date := as.IDate(date)]
table2 <- fread(
    "individual_id | date2       | company_id | alpha
       1             |  2018-01-02 |     62       |  1     
       1             |  2018-01-04 |     62       |  1.5 
       1             |  2018-01-05 |     63       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-01 |     71       |  2     
       2             |  2018-01-02 |     74       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-05 |     74       |  4",
    sep = "|"
)
table2[, date2 := as.IDate(date2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table2[table1, 
       on = "individual_id", 
       allow.cartesian = TRUE][
         date2 <= date, ][order(-date2)][, 
           .SD[1,], 
           by = .(individual_id, company_id, date)][, 
                     mean(alpha), 
                     by = .(individual_id, date)][
  order(individual_id, date)]
```

What I did there: joined tables 1 and 2 on individual, allowing for all possible combinations. Then filtered out the combinations in which `date2` was greater than `date`, so we kept dates2 prior to dates. Ordered them in descending order by date2, so we could select only the most recent occurrencies (that's what's done with `.SD[1,]`) by each `individual_id`, `company_id` and `date` combinations.

After that, it's just calculating the mean by individual and date, and sorting the table to match with your expecte output.

Comment: This looks promising, I will have to wait till Monday to test it. However, might it struggle to work with large tables? My table 1 and 2 are both over 1m rows.