# Sum the date difference using first row by group - R data table lookup

Tags: r, data.table

This is a follow on from a previous question: [Average the first row by group from data.table lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56600239/average-the-first-row-by-group-from-data-table-lookup)

I wish to be able to produce time weighted averages of alpha for an individual and the most recent for each company in the following data set:

```
table1 <- fread(
  "individual_id | date       
       1             |  2018-01-02
       1             |  2018-01-04
       1             |  2018-01-05
       2             |  2018-01-02
       2             |  2018-01-05", 
  sep ="|"
)
table1$date = as.IDate(table1$date)
table2 <- fread(
  "individual_id | date2       | company_id | alpha
       1             |  2018-01-02 |     62       |  1     
       1             |  2018-01-04 |     62       |  1.5 
       1             |  2018-01-05 |     63       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-01 |     71       |  2     
       2             |  2018-01-02 |     74       |  1   
       2             |  2018-01-05 |     74       |  4",
  sep = "|"
)
table2$date2 = as.IDate(table2$date2)
```

The first step to producing these alphas is to calculate the average by group (which I can do using the answer to my previous question), the second in to get the **time weighting**.

To do this I need to be able to sum the difference in days between the **date** (in table 1) and the date the observation was created (**date2** in table2). I also need to only do this for the most recent observation for each individual/company.

Currently I have what I thought should work:

```
table1[, time_weight := 
         #perform non-equi join
         table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
                #for each row of table1,
                by=.EACHI,
                #get most recent date difference by company_id and sum the values
                sum(.SD[, last((i.date-date2)), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
       ]
```

But this gives the following result:

```
individual_id  |    date    |  mean_alpha   |  time_weight
1        |  02/01/2018  |   1        |  0
1        |  04/01/2018  |   1.5      |  2
1        |  05/01/2018  |   1.25     |  6
2        |  02/01/2018  |   1.5      |  2
2        |  05/01/2018  |   3        |  8
```

Which is partly incorrect, for example:

Table 1:

Observation 1 - individual_id 1 and date 2018-01-02 is **correct** as the date difference is 0.
Observation 2 - individual_id 1 and date 2018-01-04 is **incorrect** as the most recent observation for company 62 is also 2018-01-04 hence a date-date2 of 0 rather than the 2 supplied.

Expected output:

```
individual_id  |    date    |  mean_alpha   |  time_weight
1        |  02/01/2018  |   1        |  0
1        |  04/01/2018  |   1.5      |  0
1        |  05/01/2018  |   1.25     |  1
2        |  02/01/2018  |   1.5      |  1
2        |  05/01/2018  |   3        |  4
```

Many thanks for the help

**End goal**

The end goal is to exponentially weight the alphas as follows:

```
table1[, time_weight := 
         #perform non-equi join
         table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
                #for each row of table1,
                by=.EACHI,
                #get most recent alpha by company_id and average the alphas
                sum(.SD[, last(alpha*exp(i.date-date2)), by=.(company_id)]$V1)/
                  sum(.SD[, last(exp(i.date-date2)), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
           ]
```

**Update**

Data table join is behaving strangely:

```
table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
       #for each row of table1,
       by=.EACHI,
       #get max alpha by company_id
       ( .SD[,max(alpha), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
```

Gives the following output as you would expect:

```
[1] 1.0 1.5 1.5 1.0 2.0 1.0 2.0 4.0
```

However, when I do this with the dates I do not get the same behaviour:

```
table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
       #for each row of table1,
       by=.EACHI,
       #get most max date by company_id
       ( .SD[,max(date2), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
```

The dates returned are:

```
[1] "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02" "2018-01-02"
[5] "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-01-01"
```

This is odd as the max date returned for item 2 should be "2018-01-04" as this is clearly present as the alpha for that date is returned. However, it is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it turns out you cannot select based on one of the join criteria, so I have to create a new column date_second_copy and then select based of this, e.g.:

```
table2$date2_copy = table2$date2

table1[, time_weight := 
         #perform non-equi join
         table2[table1, on=.(individual_id, date2<=date), 
                #for each row of table1,
                by=.EACHI,
                #get most recent date difference by company_id and sum the values
                sum(.SD[, last((i.date-date2_copy)), by=.(company_id)]$V1)]$V1
       ]
```